# creating multiple variables/lists/functions via a loop (Maxima)

Tags: maxima

below I have listed some ways to create variables/lists/functions via a for loop in Maxima,
but how, via a for loop, to do:

```
f1(x) := x^1$
f2(x) := x^2$
f3(x) := x^3$
```

example code:

```
for i : 1 thru 10 do
(x : concat ('a, i), x :: i)$
[a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10];

for i : 1 thru 3 do
(x : concat ('L, i), x :: [(3*i)-2,(3*i)-1,3*i])$
[L1, L2, L3];

/* good, but not quite what I want to do */
for i : 1 thru 3 do
f[i](x) := x^i$
[f[1](2), f[2](2), f[3](2)];

/* is there a way, via a for loop, to create */
f1(x) := x^1$
f2(x) := x^2$
f3(x) := x^3$
[f1(2), f2(2), f3(2)];
```

EDIT: further code:

```
/* is there a way, via a for loop, to create */
f(x) := x^1$
g(x) := x^2$
h(x) := x^3$
[f(2), g(2), h(2)];

for tmp1 : 1 thru 10 do
(tmp2 : parse_string(ascii(96+tmp1)), tmp2 :: tmp1)$
[a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j];

for tmp1 : 1 thru 10 do
(tmp2 : concat(parse_string(ascii(96+tmp1)), tmp1), tmp2 :: tmp1)$
[a1, b2, c3, d4, e5, f6, g7, h8, i9, j10];
```

EDIT 2: original problems solved (any code improvements/simplifications welcome):

```
for i : 1 thru 3 do
eval_string(concat("f", i, "(x) := x^", i))$
[f1(2), f2(2), f3(2)];

for i : 1 thru 3 do
eval_string(concat(ascii(96+5+i), "(x) := x^", i))$
[f(2), g(2), h(2)];

sum:0$
for i : 1 thru 3 do
sum:sum + eval_string(concat("f", i, "(2)"))$
sum;

sum:0$
for i : 1 thru 3 do
sum:sum + eval_string(concat(ascii(96+5+i), "(2)"))$
sum;
```

Comment: About edit 2, unfortunately I have to say that string operations of the kind you have shown are a very poor way to go about it. There may be circumstances in which they cannot be avoided, but it should be considered a method of last resort. Working with expressions instead of strings is almost always clearer, shorter, and more general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have collected here, various ways of creating multiple variables/lists/functions via a loop in Maxima,
as an answer to the question, '[f1(2), f2(2), f3(2)]' explicitly answers the original question:

```
for i : 1 thru 10 do
(x : concat ('a, i), x :: i)$
[a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10];

for i : 1 thru 3 do
(x : concat ('L, i), x :: [(3*i)-2,(3*i)-1,3*i])$
[L1, L2, L3];

for tmp1 : 1 thru 10 do
(tmp2 : parse_string(ascii(96+tmp1)), tmp2 :: tmp1)$
[a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j];

for tmp1 : 1 thru 10 do
(tmp2 : concat(parse_string(ascii(96+tmp1)), tmp1), tmp2 :: tmp1)$
[a1, b2, c3, d4, e5, f6, g7, h8, i9, j10];

for i : 1 thru 3 do
eval_string(concat("f", i, "(x) := x^", i))$
[f1(2), f2(2), f3(2)];

for i : 1 thru 3 do
eval_string(concat(ascii(96+5+i), "(x) := x^", i))$
[f(2), g(2), h(2)];

f[i](x) := x^i$
[f[1], f[2], f[3]];
[f[1](2), f[2](2), f[3](2)];
[f[1](u), f[2](v), f[3](w)];
```

Answer (score 1):

What is your larger goal here? In general using subscripted symbols e.g. `a[1]` instead of `a1` is to be preferred. When you define a subscripted function, you only define it once, not for every value of the subscript. E.g.

```
(%i1) f[i](x) := x^i $
(%i2) [f[1], f[2], f[3]];
                                            2                3
(%o2)         [lambda([x], x), lambda([x], x ), lambda([x], x )]
(%i3) [f[1](u), f[2](v), f[3](w)];
                                       2   3
(%o3)                             [u, v , w ]
```

If that doesn't work for you, maybe you can explain about what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: thank you, I can see that 'f[i](x) := x^i $' does more than I realised

Comment: 'f1(x)' can be preferable to 'f[1](x)'
because it's easier to type, and clearer to read, especially when x is replaced with complicated expressions or text containing square brackets
(and I may already have functions in the form 'f1,f2,f3' or 'f,g,h' etc from an existing source)

Comment: I was basically trying to establish some 'Maxima 101' general techniques,
some/all of which I'd needed at some point or another,
which any expert should know, and any beginner should want to know
(and typically when you solve one problem it helps with others,
eval_string and parse_string are very useful)

Comment: If you have just a few functions f1, f2, f3 then to me it's OK to just define them one at a time as `f1(x) := ..., f2(x) := ...,` etc. But if the subscript is a variable then it's much better to avoid constructing `concat(f, i)`. As for general techniques, it is much better in general to avoid string operations (`concat` and `eval_string` or `parse_string`). There may be some specific problems for which one must use them, but in general, it is much better to avoid them.